# store value return by mysql in php variable

Tags: php, mysql

For the code below i am trying to get the gender value in gen then store it in $gender but i am getting wrong output. I am getting `Resource id #8` as my output instead of male or female.
What shall i do to get the gender value and store it in  `$gender` with use of minimal coding.

```
$gender=mysql_query("SELECT `gender` as gen FROM `register` WHERE `reg_id` = 'reg252'");
echo $gender;
```

One way i can do is by calling something like the way below -

```
$gender=mysql_query("SELECT `gender` FROM `register` WHERE `reg_id` = 'reg252'");
while($erow = mysql_fetch_array($gender))
{
    echo $erow['gender'];
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Well, yes, `mysql_query` returns a *result set resource*, and you have figured out yourself how to get results from that result set. That's the way it works.

Comment: btw it should be `echo $erow['gen'];`

Comment: it copy paste problem i corrected the code below `as gen` is removed

Answer (score 1):

```
list($gender) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT `gender` as gen FROM `register` WHERE `reg_id` = 'reg252'"));
```

Comment: I'd advice against such one-liners, you should properly error handle the result of any and all `mysql_query` calls, not blindly feed them into the next function.

Comment: I'd advice to use PDO instead of `mysql_` functions but obviously this guy is still learning

Comment: In any case, PDO or `mysql_`, if you want to use one-liners, you should make helper functions with proper returns and exception handling.

Comment: OK so if you put next line `if(is_null($gender))` you can handle your error.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your SQL

```
SELECT `gender` as gen ...
```

While you output `echo $erow['gender'];`

So either output `echo $erow['gen'];`, either `SELECT gender FROM ...`

Comment: +1'd this as it __is__ part of the solution (which was re-done by Mina)

Comment: probably it's downvoted because you made another logical error. So either output echo $erow['gender'];, either SELECT gender FROM...It should be So either output echo $erow['gen'];, either SELECT gender FROM

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the column as gen, so you have to check gen
`echo $erow['gen'];`

In general check the comment from PeeHaa

Comment: Sorry to see other answers mentioning the same. When I submitted my answer, no answers were here. Probably we submitted them in the same second.

Comment: coorected the second one `as gen` was mistakenly there

Comment: did you try to run this Query direct on the DB, and ensure that it returns a value? "SELECT `gender` FROM `register` WHERE `reg_id` = 'reg252'"